# how to wrap axios function and let parent to wait?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, axios

here's I've my axios function wrapped within a custom function:

```
async function getOrder(orderId) {
    // ...

    await axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: endpoint + "/mymethod",
        data: request
    }).then(function (response) {
        var data = response.data.result;
        return data;
    }).catch(function (error) {
        return { "error": error };
    });
}
```

but if than i call that function:

```
router.get('/getOrder/:id', (req, res) => {
    let result = getOrder(req.params.id);
    res.json(result);
})
```

it returns nothing (since its async and don't wait the .then()).

what's the best way to wrap axios/async function and call from outside?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're missing `await` in your codes:

```
router.get('/getOrder/:id', async (req, res) => {
    let result = await getOrder(req.params.id);
    res.json(result);
})
```

====================

**[New Update]**
for me in API function:

```
async getOrder(orderId) {
    try {
      const response = await axios.post(endpoint + "/mymethod")
      return response.data
    } catch (error) {
      return { "error": error }
    }
  }
```

and get the result:

```
router.get('/getOrder/:id', async (req, res) => {
    let result = await getOrder(req.params.id);
    res.json(result);
})
```

===========

**[New Update2]** here is my sample async/await function with axios

```
const axios = require("axios")

async function getOrder(orderId) {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get("http://google.com")
    return response.data
  } catch (error) {
    return { "error": error }
  }
}


async function main() {
  let result = await getOrder();
  console.log(result, "@@")
}
main()
```

====================

**[New Update3]** new Promise with axios:

```
const axios = require("axios")

async function getOrder(orderId) {
  // try {
  //   const response = await axios.get("http://google.com")
  //   return response.data
  // } catch (error) {
  //   return { "error": error }
  // }
  return await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    axios({
      method: 'get',
      url: "http://google.com"
    }).then(function (response) {
      var data = response.data
      resolve(data)
    }).catch(function (error) {
      reject({ "error": error })
    });
  })
}


async function main() {
  let result = await getOrder();
  console.log(result, "@@")
}
main()
```

Comment: nope: "SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules"

Comment: `await` should be existing in `async` function. Have you add `async` before your function header?

Comment: @markzzz Did you add the `async` to the `router.get` paramater? This answer is valid with the update to return the promised data in `getOrder`

Comment: if I do this, "result" will be undefined :O (usint .then(), not your code)

Comment: `.then()` is a callback function, if u wanna to use that, suggesting to use `new Promise` in getOrder function for return your result

Comment: new Promise version updated

Answer (score -1):

I think you are missing an await so you do not return a promise but wait for the result of getOrder to be passed in res.json :

```
router.get('/getOrder/:id', async (req, res) => {
        let result = await getOrder(req.params.id);
        res.json(result);
    })
```

Comment: nope: "SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules"