# NextJS calling a API after request

Tags: node.js, api, next.js

I am using a webhooks on BigCommerce. They are calling a my api/webhooks/addtocart when ever user added item to cart.

I wrote following code there.

```
import {NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse} from 'next';

let axios = require("axios").default;

export default async function product(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
    try {
        let id = req.body.data.id;
        console.log(id)
        res.send('OK')

    } catch (error) {
        const {message, response} = error;
        res.status(response?.status || 500).json({message});
    }

}
```

With the id I can obtain the cart ID. I want to use that cart ID to get the data on that cart. So I need to create a GET to
[https://api.bigcommerce.com/stores/{store_hash}/v3/carts/{cartId}](https://api.bigcommerce.com/stores/%7Bstore_hash%7D/v3/carts/%7BcartId%7D)

I wrote this code before the line `res.send('OK')`. I never returned a result.

```
var options = {
  method: 'GET',
  url: 'https://api.bigcommerce.com/stores/{store_hash}/v3/carts/{id}',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    Accept: 'application/json',
    'X-Auth-Token': 'aqqeqzgjinaow54rzzalyk6wban6wa4'
  }
};

axios.request(options).then(function (response) {
  console.log(response.data);
}).catch(function (error) {
  console.error(error);
});
```

Anyone help me to get these done?

Highly appreciate your help since I am new here.

Thanks for your time

Comment: `res.send` runs before `axios` is finished. see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72685187/how-to-wrap-axios-function-and-let-parent-to-wait

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`axios.request(options)` returns a [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), which means you need to `await` it, or use `res.send` in the `.then` handler.

Simplified version using `await`:

```
export default async function product(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) { 
  let id = req.body.data.id;
  const { data } = await axios.request({ method: 'GET', ... });
  console.log(data)
  res.send('OK')
}
```